# Extracting XY Coordinates from QTCharts (a line series) on Mouse click

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I'm trying to pick the X and Y Coordinates from a 2D Chart in QT when a mouse click is done on the 2D Chart widget.

I tried to use the mapFromScene , mapToValue and other similar functions that are available in the QTChart Library. But I'm unable to get the values.

[image: Sample 2D Chart]

[image: Expected Output for XY Co-ords Extraction]

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the expected output for this problem.

This is my Code which works fine for me.

```
// function for mouse press events
void 2D_Graph::mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent * e) {
    if(chartView->chart()->isEnabled()) {
        auto curPoint = QCursor::pos();
        curPoint = chartView->mapFromGlobal(curPoint);
        auto pickVal = chartView->mapToScene(curPoint);
        pickVal = chartView->chart()->mapFromScene(curPoint);
        pickVal = chartView->chart()->mapToValue(curPoint,chartView->chart()->series().at(0));
        qDebug() << "Diagram Picked Value : " << pickVal;
    }
}
```